# OCaml syntax error in function

Tags: function, syntax, syntax-error, ocaml

I have to create a function which will display each element from a set of strings. I did the following:

```
module S = Set.Make(String);;
module P = Pervasives;;
let write x = (
        P.print_string("{"); let first = true;
    S.iter (fun str -> (if first then () else P.print_string(","); P.print_string(str))) x;
    P.print_string("}");
    P.print_newline
  );;
  ^
```

At the end of the program (where I placed that sign) it appears I have an error: Syntax error: operator expected.
Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe your syntactic problem is with `let`. Except in top-level code (outermost level of a module), `let` must be followed by `in`.

There are many other problems with this code, but maybe this will let you find the next problem :-)

A few notes:

Variables in OCaml are immutable. So your variable named `first` will always be true. You can't change it. This (seemingly minor) point is one of the keys to functional programming.

You don't need to reference the `Pervasives` module by name. That's why it's called "pervasive". You can just say `print_string` by itself.

Your last call to `print_newline` isn't a call. This expression just evaluates to the function itself. (You need to give it an argument if you want to call the function.)

Comment: Thank you! I just started using oCaml at my university so I am a total outsider. Is there any way I can execute a block of code only at the first element of the set?

Comment: One way that's good style might be to fold over the set rather than iterating. A fold lets you carry state along (which is what you want to do).

Comment: I wrote the code using a fold rather the iter, which works how I wanted it to. My only problem is that the exercise I am trying to solve, particularly asks me to use iter. I can solve it with iter, but the I will display it like: {string1,string2,}. I will have an extra comma before the bracket.

Comment: `List.iter` is an imperative-style construct. So you're more or less forced to use other imperative OCaml features to make it do what you want. You can have mutable state in OCaml: start with `let start = ref true`. But this just postpones learning how FP actually works (IMHO :-)

Comment: "This (seemingly minor) point is one of the keys to functional programming." Not necessarily. Scheme is a functional language, and lets you assign to variables. If you're trying to say "purely functional", then OCaml is not a purely functional language anyway. Not being able to assign to variables is just a feature of the ML family of languages.

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing the semicolon after the `let first = true` with the keyword `in`.